# Link with hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need something link this

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top-55
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it works only for that link `<a href="#offer">offer</a>`. I want that this code works for this link for example `<a href="offer.html#offer2">offer2</a>`

Comment: Note that fragment identifiers are sometimes tricky to test : if you change it by hand in the address bar, you'll need to force page refresh as just hitting enter won't actually do much.

Answer (score 0):

I think your jquery selector is wrong.

See
http://jsfiddle.net/9shvmhwh/5/

```
 $(function() {
       $("a[href*='#']:not([href='#'])").click(function(event) {
            location = $(this).attr('href');
            event.stopPropgation();
            return true;
       });
    });
```